# Return from Shellcode instead of exit

Tags: c, macos, assembly, shellcode

I'm working on a shared mem assignment for uni and I've 'borrowed' and 'massaged' some shellcode I've seen in posts I've read here and other places.  I've been able to construct an example that runs on my MacBook (Mojave) and almost does what I want.

However, since I'm not that experienced with assembly programming in an OS environment (MacOS in this case), and because I don't fully understand the assembly below, I need a little help to overcome my last issue.

In my C boilerplate wrapper, I have a loop that calls my shellcode periodically, but the loop only executes one iteration.  This leads me to the conclusion that the second `syscall` (in the code below) is performing an `exit 0`, thus terminating the process.

How can I modify the assembly to *return* instead of *exit*?

*Note* if asked, I can post more information about the wrapper code and tools I'm using.

```
bits 64

Section .text
  global start

start:
  jmp       short MESSAGE     ;00000000  EB24              jmp short 0x26

GOBACK:
  mov       eax, 0x2000004    ;00000002  B804000002        mov eax,0x2000004  ; write
  mov       edi, 0x1          ;00000007  BF01000000        mov edi,0x1
  lea       rsi, [rel msg]    ;0000000C  488D3518000000    lea rsi,[rel 0x2b]
  mov       edx, 0xf          ;00000013  BA0F000000        mov edx,0xf
  syscall                     ;00000018  0F05              syscall

  mov       eax,0x2000001     ;0000001A  B801000002        mov eax,0x2000001  ;exit
  mov       edi,0x0           ;0000001F  BF00000000        mov edi,0x0
  syscall                     ;00000024  0F05              syscall


MESSAGE:
  call      GOBACK
  msg:      db      "Hello, world!", 0dh, 0ah
  .len:     equ     $ - msg
```

Here is my C boilerplate code, which includes the shellcode from above.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x24\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x02\xbf\x01\x00\x00\x00\x48\x8d\x35\x18\x00\x00\x00\xba\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x02\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05\xe8\xd7\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x0d\x0a";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  void *mem = mmap(0, sizeof(shellcode), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  memcpy(mem, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

  mprotect(mem, sizeof(shellcode), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int (*func)();
    func = (int (*)())mem;
    (int)(*func)();
    sleep(5);
  }

  munmap(mem, sizeof(shellcode));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you know where you would like to `ret`urn?

Comment: If you want to `ret` from it, you're just writing a function in machine code instead of asm.  It's not something that would work if you injected this code as part of a buffer overflow because it wouldn't be called with a return address on the stack (unless your payload includes an extra return address).

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes I can see what you mean.  Its just that I haven't done any assembly level coding in a while and I wasn't sure if a system call was needed in order to return.

Comment: Look at compiler-generated code for whole functions.  That's what the `ret` instruction is for!  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/a/38552509)  (Using a system call to modify the architectural state of your own thread, like setting the program counter (RIP), would be insanely slow.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a loop that calls my shellcode

So if it's an actual `call` then you are good to go and the only change you need to do is to remove the 3 last instructions (`mov`, `mov` and `syscall`) and replaced them with a `ret` since the return address will be on the stack already. But we need to additionally clean up the stack a little bit since the address of the text string is put there for the sake of `syscall`, we want to get rid of it before the return.

Also since you shellcode contains an offset (the first `jmp` opcode with the value of `0x24`) it's safer to not delete anything (as it will change the offsets) but to replace with `NOP`. Unless you modify the shellcode's source code and generate it every time - than it's fine to remove stuff.

So what I would actually propose to do is to replace the bytes that constitutes for the last 3 opcodes with `0x90`(NOP) and the last 2 bytes from that replace with `pop rax\ret` so bytes `0x58` and `0xc3`. The final shellcode could look like this:

```
const char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x24\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x02\xbf\x01\x00\x00\x00\x48\x8d\x35\x18\x00\x00\x00\xba\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x58\xc3\xe8\xd7\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x0d\x0a";
```

Comment: Thanks! After reading your comment and answer, I've added the boilerplate to show how I execute the shellcode.  It's through a function call.  I'll try to digest your advice and see what I can achieve.

Comment: Using your 1st suggestion resulted in a seg fault after printing hello the first time.  How can I get the address to return to, and do I need to push anything onto the stack at the start of the shellcode?

Comment: thanks for the code. I'll check it today and update the answer

Comment: I've updated the answer it should be ok - though I will be able to verify this on MacOS tomorrow unless it will work for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm generating the shellcode from Assembly source using NASM.  I'm using Shellme.py to extract the bytecode from the object file.  I had to modify Shellme a little to handle the case when objdump is not able to disassemble the instruction and uses the label `<unknown>` instead of the mnemonic.

Comment: Interesting.  It worked after I removed the following `00000026  E8D7FFFFFF        call 0x2` from the shellcode.  I've seen examples with that line in the source, but my NASM (Homebrew v2.14.02) issues an error for that line:  `27: error: unable to find a suitable absolute  symbol for this reference`, so I remove it (and it still works).